# make simple limitation for getting data from server

Tags: flutter, dart

in this below part of my application i would like to make simple limitation for getting data from server when i click on clicking on button, in fact when i click on button i want to check simple variable as `lastGetDataTimeStamp`

my code and getting data from server only work on first initial application and method, how can i resolve that?

```
  final MyApi _api;
  int lastGetDataTimeStamp = 0;
  bool _isExpanded = false;

  bool get isExpanded => _isExpanded;


  Future<Response<BuiltAccountData>> getLatestStories(bool canGet) {
    if(canGet){
      DateTime currentTime = DateTime.now();
      var date = new DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(lastGetDataTimeStamp * 1000);
      var diff = currentTime.difference(date);

      if (diff.inMinutes >= 3) {
        lastGetDataTimeStamp = DateTime.now().toUtc().millisecondsSinceEpoch;
        BuiltLogin login = BuiltLogin((b) => b
          ..page_name = ''
          ..page_password = '');
        return _api.getLatestStoriesList(login);
      } else {
        return null;
      }
    }else{
      return null;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better to utilize `DateTime` methods, instead of converting to millies and making logic complex. For me following code is working.

**Note:** you might want to make `_lastAccessedAt` a global variable, as the object invoking this code might get reconstructed. If it is alive all the times, then no need to make it global.

```
  // Note: You might want to make this a global variable depending on this class lifetime.
  DateTime _lastAccessedAt;

  Future<Response<BuiltAccountData>> getLatestStories(bool canGet) {
    if (!canGet) {
      print("Can't get");
      return Future.value(null);
    }
    // Remove below block. Only for debugging.
    if (_lastAccessedAt != null) {
      print("Diff: ${DateTime.now().difference(_lastAccessedAt).inSeconds} secs");
    }

    if (_lastAccessedAt != null && DateTime.now().difference(_lastAccessedAt).inMinutes < 3) {
      print("Ignoring request as last access time is less than 3mins");
      return Future.value(null);
    }
    _lastAccessedAt = DateTime.now();
    print("Sending to server");
    /* Your logic goes here*/
    ...
  }
```